MariaDB-Backup: Failed To Validate First Page Of File: Error 40
Hoping someone can help with this:
I'm running a simple mariadb-backup --backup and I get the following error:
2024-12-12 16:38:35 mariabackup: Generating a list of tablespaces
2024-12-12 16:38:35 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace: ./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd uses space ID: 5. Cannot open filepath: ./stepca/x509_certs.ibd which uses the same space ID.
[00] FATAL ERROR: 2024-12-12 16:38:35 Failed to validate first page of the file stepca/x509_certs, error 40

I have a sneaking suspicion that this may have been caused when the box was updated from MariaDB 10.?.? (10.5.? I think) to the current 11.4.4 (I know I know, stupid me!)
This is the first backup I've tried, so there is no "fallback"  :-(
There are no DBs on the box apart from the Step-CA one.
Can someone please let me know how to fix this? I've looked, but I can't seem to find anything (hence me asking). :-)
I suppose my ultimate solution is to blow the DB away and re-create it - but that means having to reinitialise all our the internal SSH and TLS Certificates (Step-CA is the internal Certificate Authority for the network) - a PITA, but doable.
Thanks in advance
Dulux-Oz

The only option is to restore a backup. When you do not have one, the only option is to re-install en re-create your certificates..... and, almost forgot CREATE A BACKUP !! (and verify that you are able to restore it, when needed....)

The problem is likely a conflict in tablespace IDs after upgrading from MariaDB 10.x to 11.4.4.
This issue often happens when an InnoDB tablespace file gets corrupted. I am sharing few steps that you can try to resolve this issue:
Verify the Tablespace Conflict:
mariadb -e "SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES WHERE SPACE = 5;
Fix or Drop Problematic Table:
If stepca.x509_certs is not critical, you can drop and recreate it:
DROP TABLE stepca.x509_certs;
Export & Reinitialize (Last Resort)
If unresolved, export your database with mysqldump, reinitialize the server, and re-import the data.
Hope it helps!
